# How is מְצַוְּךָ pronounced?

Tags: hebrew, pentateuch-chumash

A simple question for the users here. I have just started learning how to read Hebrew to read the Scriptures so I am finding difficult words for me. I am confused about the וְּ in it.

Thanks

Andy

Comment: Our system of pointing vowels (:niqud") and of trop is the Tiberian System. Other systems exist; Yemenite Jews use both Tiberian and Babylonian niqud. But nowadays, when you say "niqud" or "trop" and aren't an acacemic, you mean Tiberian. Invented by Mesoretes in North Israel in 6th-10th cent CE.

Comment: The problem is, the Tiberian Mesoretes used a dot in the letter just to draw your attention to it, and therefore the dot serves multiple uses. In the six letters בג"ד כפ"ת it changes the sound of the letter. (And in their accent, all 6 letters had pairs of sounds; not like ג or ד in Ashkenazic, Sepharadic or Modern Israeli accents.)

Comment: It is also used to tell you the letter is doubled -- serving to both close 1 syllable and start the next. And in that case, the root would have 2 copies of the letter: e.g. the root /pll/ gives us the word "tefillah" (prayer) with a dotted lamed. Three syllables te.fil.lah, but blend it into a long /l/ sound. (The "LL" in the English word "bullet" should be similar.)

Comment: In a final ה, it's to tell you the hei isn't silent, as we expect at the end of the word. Use for feminine posessive. "Ishah" - woman. "Ishahh" -- her man.

Not to mention your case: the shuruq (a/k/a melupum) vowel, the full spelling of the /OO/ sound. Vav with yet another use of the dot. Looks just like a doubled vav. This word has the latter. "Metzavvekha" (in most contemporary accents; also "messawwekha" or "mechawwekha", etc...)

And one sign with all those different uses is where the ambiguity that confused you comes from.